# Formatting a string with string.Format("{0:00}"

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-4.0, string-formatting

I have just taken over some code and I see this used a lot. It seems to take the integer and create a string looking like "01", "02" etc.

What I am not sure of is the convention used here. Why is the format `{0:00}` and not `{00}`?

```
string.Format("{0:00}", int.Parse(testVal) + 1);
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The first `0` is the placeholder, means the first parameter.
`00` is an actual format.

For example it could be like this:

```
var result = string.Format("{0:00} - {1:00}", 5, 6);
```

`result` will be `05 - 06`. So the first 0 is means take the first parameter 5, while 1 means to take parameter 6.

The format is `{index[,length][:formatString]}`. Take a look at [String.Format Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

The first `0` in the following line is for the index of your argument

```
string.Format("{0:00}", int.Parse(testVal) + 1);
```

`(int.Parse(testVal) + 1).ToString ("00")` will yield the same thing.

`string.Format` supports multiple substitutions like this:

```
string.Format("{0:00} + 1 = {1:00}", int.Parse(testVal), int.Parse(testVal) + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The leading `0` in the format string `{0:00}` indicates the *index* of this formatter specification. The MSDN documentation for [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) has this to say about the index...

> *index:* The zero-based position in the parameter list of the object to be formatted.